# Observable List only saving the first row of mysql table

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have an Observable List of students and I am trying to populate it from my Student table in mysql. The first student gets saved but then later gets overriden by the second Student and my observable list just ends up with a duplicate of the second student. How do i get it to correct save all of the students in my table to my observable list? Thank you in Advance

```
/method to return all of the students in the database in an observable list of students
public ObservableList<Student> getStudents() {

    
    String getStudentQuery = "SELECT * FROM StudentManagment.Student ";
    Student tempstudent = new Student();
    Name name = new Name();
    DOB dob = new DOB();
    
    
    try {
        connect();
        rs=st.executeQuery(getStudentQuery);
        while(rs.next()) {  
            tempstudent.setID(rs.getInt("idStudent"));
            name.setFirstName(rs.getString("firstName"));
            name.setMiddleInitial(rs.getString("middleInitial"));
            name.setLastName(rs.getString("lastName"));
            dob.setDateOfBirth(rs.getString("DateOfBirth"));
            tempstudent.setName(name);
            tempstudent.setDob(dob);
            students.add(tempstudent);                      //adding the temporary student to the student observable list
           
        }
        
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    
    
          return students;                                  //returning the observable list
}
```

Comment: `Student tempstudent = new Student();` should be the first line in the `while-loop`.

Comment: Probably same for name and dob.

Comment: This worked thank you. Can you explain why it had to be the first line in the while loop please

Comment: Outside of the `while-loop`, you create one `Student` and constantly rewrite its data each time the loop runs. Once you add it to the `while-loop`, you create a new `Student` each time the loop runs.

Answer (score 1):

Java uses pass by reference, not pass by value. So when you add tempstudent object in the list java stores the reference of the tempstudent in the list.

> Student tempstudent = new Student();

For java there is only tempstudent, so it's values are same also.

What you can do is create a new instance of the Student and then add that in the Students list. So the code should be:

```
public ObservableList<Student> getStudents() {


String getStudentQuery = "SELECT * FROM StudentManagment.Student ";
   
try {
    connect();
    rs=st.executeQuery(getStudentQuery);
    while(rs.next()) {
        Student tempstudent = new Student();
        Name name = new Name();
        DOB dob = new DOB();
        tempstudent.setID(rs.getInt("idStudent"));
        name.setFirstName(rs.getString("firstName"));
        name.setMiddleInitial(rs.getString("middleInitial"));
        name.setLastName(rs.getString("lastName"));
        dob.setDateOfBirth(rs.getString("DateOfBirth"));
        tempstudent.setName(name);
        tempstudent.setDob(dob);
        students.add(tempstudent);                     
       
    }
    
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}   


      return students;                                  //returning the observable list
```

}